# IDE doesn't see my class object attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes, setattr

When I create attributes of class object with `setattr()` function:

```
class Dict_to_class():
def __init__(self, initDict):
    for key, value in initDict.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
    self.class_Names = initDict
```

I can't see what attributes it has, later:
[image: This is autocomplete pic]

I understand, that this is because these attributes are created dynamically and are not declared as `class_Names`

1. Is it any chance to make the rest of them visible for autocomplete?
2. How can I make my object of class show all attributes it has?

Comment: It can't see them since you add them at run time

Comment: If your IDE supports it you can attempt to use tools such as TabNine (with which I have zero affiliation) but its suggestions will be largely based on a guess

Comment: @DeepSpace, the problem is not in IDE autocomplete only. Pylint doesn't like these added arguments too. It says: 
`E1101: Instance of 'DicToClass' has no 'key' member (no-member)`